# Possible to recreate LVM VG?

Tags: linux, lvm

frequent listener first time caller

A coworker in another department did an OS upgrade on a CentOS-based RAID NAS. Unfortunately the upgrade process recreated the PV that defined the VG. Basically LVM sees the PV on the RAID array, but does not see any VGs. This is an 80 TB array, with no backups. I have been brought over to help, but I don't use LVM that much so limited help.

Here's where we are at

```
$ pvs /dev/sda2
PV         VG  Fmt   Attr  Psize   Pfree   DevSize
/dev/sda2      lvm2  a--   76.40t  76.40t  76.40t 

$ pvdisplay /dev/sda2
-- NEW Physical volume --
PV Name       /dev/sda2
VG Name
PV Size       76.4 TiB
Allocatable   NO
PE Size       0
Total PE      0
Free PE       0
Allocated PE  0
PV UUID       <UUID>
```

If I cat the raw partition I can see some filesystem data, so I am hoping that I can redefine the VG and reconstruct the partition from there. Its my understanding that LVM retains internal backups of the metadata, so I'm wondering if the old VG data is on the disk somewhere, even though the PV has been recreated?

Any other advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you get to the old /etc directory? The LVM archives you'd use for recovery are in /etc/lvm/archives.

Comment: Try this help: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/mdatarecover.html